# Strange drop shadow appears on my programmatically drawn view

Tags: ios

I can't explain it, but my programmatically drawn views suddenly have drop shadows. It was working as it should, but somewhere along the line, it stopped. The code that I was editing doesn't even run before this bug.

I've tried to research, but unfortunately, too many people want to add a drop shadow.

Update: It is due to something that happens when dragging/moving the view (as it happens when entering the view through the right menu, but not otherwise). I haven't solved it yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was due to background animations being visible behind the transparent view.

Solution

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```